# How to install Django project with all modules?

Tags: django, installation

I created a Django's application which use some additional modules like crispy_forms. I would like to send this application to my friends to test it. 
But I don't know how can they just install it and run it? Is it possible? 
Application using also database PostgreSQL. 
What is the simplest way to just run this application from any place with no errors and problems on the start?

I found only information about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/ 
and packed my app, but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: You can use [requirments.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file to state project requirements.

Comment: I know, but even if I have it what is next? How can I install app and run it? I dwonload app, unpack and want to run.

Comment: You can also send them code directly alongwith installation instructions. They'll need to have Python and PostgreSQL installed and python packages in requirements.txt can be installed directly using pip.

Comment: Ok, so they will need go into project folder where requirements.txt is placed and then call pip install command yes? Is it possible to make it simpler?

Comment: Or do you want to simply showcase your project to your friends without sharing the code? For that you can run `python manage.py runserver <your_public_ip>:<port>`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. And no, I don't think it can be made any simpler.

Comment: No, I know I could do it this way but I do not uploaded my app anywhere. I want only send them my zip app and they can just run it with no need to install additional modules included in application (it should be done automatically)

Answer (score 1):

To setup env for project i would install virtualenv, then:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You need to set database connection in settings.py, or switch to sqlite3...

hope this helps!

Comment: I hope it could help. I generated all modules needed for my project and install it with this command. Looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual environment then activate it and go in your project root.
If you are not using virtualenvironment then do the same thing, go in your project root.
Make sure you have requirements.txt file.

run the command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will add automatically all your modules to requirements.txt file

which can be then installed by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```